# Is it possible to create a VS Studio 2019 (IDE) Project for ROS2?

Tags: ros, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm learning ROS2 on Windows. I manage to install ROS2 foxy and it's working fine. Now I have to start my project, I tried to write a simple publisher including:

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
```

If I open it with VS, intellisense doesn't work. For example I don't have any highlighting on:

```
rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr publisher_;
```

Searching on Google I found 2 way to have the Intellisense suggestions:

1. Use VS Code with the ROS extension.
2. Create a VS (IDE) project and to setup the VC++ directories path, in Project Options.

Since I have VS 2019 already installed, I would like to use the second one, but I don't understand if it's possible. I mean: if I create a VS studio project containing all the ros package files (CMakeLists, package.xml ecc.), can I still build my package with `colcon build`?  How should I build it? I have the feeling that .vcxproj file is something "incomprehensible" for the ros ws.

Is it better/easier to use VS Code to write the code, and then keep doing `colcon build` and `ros2 run ..` with the prompt command?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397528/is-it-possible-to-create-a-vs-studio-2019-(ide)-project-for-ros2?/) by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2022-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding VS IDE, I noticed that `colcon build` creates some **.vcxproj files** in the build folder, but I think I should't touch them (**!SEE EDIT!**).

So I was tired of searching and I decided to install **VS Code**.
Then, in order to make Intellisense work, I added into **c_cpp_properties.json** *includePath* the include folder of *rclcpp.hpp* and any other libraries I need. There are a lot of tutorial about it on Google.

I didn't install the ROS extension since I'm fine using the prompt to build and run the package.

VS Code seems to work as I expect, so for me this is the solution. If you have more knowledge or if I missed something, feel free to answer.

**EDIT**: I was wrong! **Visual Studio project is always created**!

The whole question was badly asked. I thought that first I had to create a VS project, where I would put the entire ros package; and then build it with ros command (and I couldn't understand how). **The reality is** that I only need to create a ros package with some source .cpp file, with whatever editor I want; and then setup CMakeLists. This way, when I build the code with `colcon build`,  it automatically creates some VS project (in build folder). One of them has the same name of my node and has the project properties I specified in the CMakeLists. Moreover, I can edit the .cpp file of that project directly from **Visual Studio**. Regarding Intellisense, I have no more red squiggles in Visual Studio because now I imported all I need.

So in the end:

- You can freely use **Visual Studio** (IDE) + command prompt to build and run the nodes
- You set all dependecies through **CMakeLists**, and they will be set automatically for the visual studio project after the build.

Sorry if all of these things may seem obvious, but they weren't so clear to me. I leave the post here, maybe it could help someone in the future.

---

Originally posted by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) with karma: 100 on 2022-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1